# Using Angular ng-If to build views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm working with Ionic(1.3.1)

I have an rootscope array with currently 4 items.

```
$rootScope.special= [
        { title: 'item1', id: 1 },
        { title: 'item2', id: 2 },
        { title: 'item3', id: 3 },
        { title: 'item4', id: 4 }
    ];
```

Each item belongs to the same category and the route to see them is the same (homepage -> item), currently my view is this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{specialItemName}}">


<ion-content>

    <div class="feedback-view" ng-if="state == 'app.special/Item-1' ">
        <item-1-directive></item-1-directive>
    </div>

    <div class="eq-view" ng-if="state == 'app.special/Item-2' ">
        <item-2-directive></item-2-directive>
    </div>

    <div class="pan-view" ng-if="state == 'app.special/Item-3' ">
        <item-3-directive></item-3-directive>
    </div>

    <div class="pan-view" ng-if="state == 'app.special/Item-4' ">
        <item-4-directive></item-4-directive>
    </div>

</ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Since the items views are different I need to build a special directive for each one so I can't just change the model of an specific view.

I was wondering, can I (somehow) let Angular to build this div/directive structure? So in case I need to add more items (with other names than "item-1") I do not need to change the view. Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $root.special" ng-if="state == 'app.item/{{item.title}}' ">
        <{{item.title}}-directive></{{item.title}}-directive>
      </div>
```

That of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger directive with ng-class in runtime, I would recommend something like:

```
<div ng-switch="state">
    <div dir-a ng-switch-when="state/a"></div>
    <div dir-b ng-switch-when="state/b"></div>
    <div dir-c ng-switch-when="state/c"></div>
</div>
```

here is a little codepen: http://codepen.io/shotap/pen/RGWvGb?editors=1010

if your not familiar with `ngSwitch`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: That is less code. But I have to add a new div every time I have a new item, don't?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` in order to invoke a directive

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $root.special" ng-if="state == 'app.item/{{item.title}}' ">
        <div class="{{item.title}}-directive"></div>
</div>
```

add to the directive a restrict property:

```
restrict : "C"
```

Comment: This ng-if doesn't work for me `ng-if="state == 'app.item/{{item.title}}' "` it does not parse the item.title var

Comment: yea you need to remove the {{}}: ng-if="state == 'app.item/' + item.title"